# Drawing a Gradient Line with LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, gradient, msaa

I'm really new to Android App development/LibGDX but very familiar with Java.
I'm struggling to create a gradiented line looking like the one shown in the image, in LibGDX.

[image: http://i57.tinypic.com/icigqf.png]

(I think it looks really amazing tbh oO)
Note: The image was a screenshot from the Java Applet I'm trying to port.

So far, I've found little to no information as to how to draw with gradients.

If it's not possible to draw, is there a chance to e.g. create a gradient in photoshop and put it in a layer behind a black layer covering it and then just "removing" the black layer for the coordinates of the line?

**Gradient is not visible**

.........Gradient
---------Black
^^       Line removes Black

*Results in ->*

.........Gradient
---  ----Black

**Gradient is visible for coordinates of the line (?)**

EDIT: I want the lines to be antialiased as well. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Have you tried using Pixmaps? It can be done with little calculation and nested for loop. :-) Im not at home so I dont have an example code. But you can figure it out.

Comment: I'll have a look at that, thanks. Will post how it goes cause I think many have the same problem :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the ShapeRender class: [Reference](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html)

Something like:

```
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
shapeRenderer.line(x, y, x2, y2, Color.RED, Color.GREEN);
shapeRenderer.end();
```

And maybe tweak the line width with: `Gdx.gl20.glLineWidth(float width)`.

Comment: I have that bit of code already, thanks. What my real problem is, ist that i want the lines to be a) filled with a gradient that is not from two Colors but from many. If you know how Java g2d works i think you know what I mean. You can define a gradient that starts from 0/0 and goes to 1920/1080 and has 4 different colors and then draw a line with that gradient. That'll create the look of the picture above :/